# Oracle PL-SQL : Using multiple methods to generate an unique condition through dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables. First table contain the conditions/methods and their relations – COND_REL. Business enters/inputs the conditions into COND_REL table. Business updates data in CONDITION_NAME every week.
Second table CONCAT_REL is the final output table after getting all the unique CONDITION_NAMEs.

Using dynamic SQLs in COND_REL table, I need to concatenate the conditions and make unique conditions/methods. This table name is CONCAT_REL. So, could you please help me achieve it as I was able to achieve only a hard-coded/normal concatenation but unable to figure out dynamic SQL concatenation.

Please find the table structures below.

```
COND_REL table

    CONDTION_NAME          FILD            OPERTION       VALUE         OPERND
    METHOD1            SHIPMENT_MODE           =         AIRWAY           AND
    METHOD1                TYP                 =         BOX              OR
    METHOD1                TYP                 =         ENVELOPE      
    METHOD2            SHIPMENT_MODE           =         RAIL_ROAD        AND
    METHOD2                TYP                 =         CONTAINER        AND
    METHOD2            DELIVERY_PH             <>         CALL            AND
    METHOD2            DELIVERY_TYP            =         HOUSE        
    METHOD3                TYP                 =         FRAGILE          AND
    METHOD3            DELIVERY_PH             =         TEXT             OR
    METHOD3            DELIVERY_TYP            =         OFFICE        
    METHOD4            ACKNOWLDGE              =         YES

CONCAT_REL table 

    UNIQUE_MET                     UNIQUE_EXPRESION
    METHOD1        SHIPMENT_MODE = 'AIRWAY' AND TYP = 'BOX' OR TYP = 'ENVELOPE'
    METHOD2        SHIPMENT_MODE = 'RAIL_ROAD' AND TYP = 'CONTAINER' AND DELIVERY_PH <> 'CALL'AND DELIVERY_TYP = 'HOUSE'        
    METHOD3        TYP = 'FRAGILE' AND DELIVERY_PH = 'TEXT' OR DELIVERY_TYP = 'OFFICE'
    METHOD4            ACKNOWLDGE              =         YES
```

Comment: How do you know what order to combine the rows in `cond_rel` to get to `concat_rel`? 
 `SHIPMENT_MODE = 'AIRWAY' AND TYP = 'BOX' OR TYP = 'ENVELOPE'` is logically different from `SHIPMENT_MODE = 'AIRWAY' OR TYP = 'ENVELOPE' AND TYP = 'BOX'`.  But nothing in the `cond_rel` table appears to tell us which expression you meant.  Realistically, you'd want at least a sort column.  But more likely, you'd need some way of grouping expressions together.

Comment: @JustinCave It is concatenation based on CONDITION_NAME. When it encounters METHOD1, we need to concatenate all the values in it and write the unique method as METHOD1 into CONCAT_REL table. 
When it encounters METHOD2,  we need to concatenate all the values in it and write the unique method as METHOD2 into CONCAT_REL table.

Comment: Right.  But data in tables is inherently unordered.  If I get back the 3 `method1` rows with no `order by`, Oracle is free to return them in any order it chooses.  But you care what order the rows are returned in because the expressions you build are logically different depending on order.  Thus you'd need some sort of `order_by` column or some other way to group expressions together.  Or, I suppose, you could say that you're equally happy with any of several logically distinct results but that seems unlikely

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Oracle will return them in any order. However my main worry is not about the order but I need to get various distinct results. This would help me analyse and refine it for further processing in business layer level.

Comment: OK.  I'm not sure how your main worry could be something other than getting correct results.   But if you don't care about correctness, I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have an `ordering` column that specifies the order of the conditions, you can use:

```sql
WITH conditions ( condition_name, comparison, operand, ordering ) AS (
  SELECT condition_name,
         field || ' ' || operation || ' ''' || REPLACE(value, '''', '''''') || '''',
         operand,
         ordering
  FROM   cond_rel
),
grouped_or ( condition, comparison, operand, ordering ) AS (
  SELECT condition_name,
         CASE COUNT(*)
         WHEN 1
         THEN MAX(comparison)
         ELSE '('||LISTAGG(comparison, ' OR ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ordering)||')'
         END,
         MAX(operand)  KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ordering),
         MAX(ordering) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ordering)
  FROM   conditions
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY condition_name
    ORDER     BY ordering
    MEASURES
      MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN ( or_operands* any_operand )
    DEFINE or_operands AS operand = 'OR'
  )
  GROUP BY condition_name, mno
)
SELECT condition,
       LISTAGG(comparison, ' AND ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ordering)
         AS unique_expression
FROM   grouped_or
GROUP BY condition;
```

*Note: `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` so, if you naively concatenate then you may get different result than you expect. Instead you need to process the consecutive `OR` conditions first and put then into brackets and then concatenate the `AND` conditions.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE COND_REL( CONDITION_NAME, FIELD, OPERATION, VALUE, OPERAND, ORDERING ) AS
SELECT 'METHOD1', 'SHIPMENT_MODE', '=',  'AIRWAY',     'AND', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD1', 'TYP',           '=',  'BOX',        'OR',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD1', 'TYP',           '=',  'ENVELOPE',   NULL,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD2', 'SHIPMENT_MODE', '=',  'RAIL_ROAD',  'AND', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD2', 'TYP',           '=',  'CONTAINER',  'AND', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD2', 'DELIVERY_PH',   '<>', 'CALL',       'AND', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD2', 'DELIVERY_TYP',  '=',  'HOUSE',      NULL,  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD3', 'TYP',           '=',  'FRAGILE',    'AND', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD3', 'DELIVERY_PH',   '=',  'TEXT',       'OR',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD3', 'DELIVERY_TYP',  '=',  'OFFICE',     NULL,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'METHOD4', 'ACKNOWLDGE',    '=',  'YES',        NULL,  1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CONDITION | UNIQUE_EXPRESSION |
> | --- | --- |
> | METHOD1 | `SHIPMENT_MODE = 'AIRWAY' AND (TYP = 'BOX' OR TYP = 'ENVELOPE')` |
> | METHOD2 | `SHIPMENT_MODE = 'RAIL_ROAD' AND TYP = 'CONTAINER' AND DELIVERY_PH <> 'CALL' AND DELIVERY_TYP = 'HOUSE'` |
> | METHOD3 | `TYP = 'FRAGILE' AND (DELIVERY_PH = 'TEXT' OR DELIVERY_TYP = 'OFFICE')` |
> | METHOD4 | `ACKNOWLDGE = 'YES'` |

---

If you want to just concatenate the rows without respect to precedence of the logical operators then:

```sql
SELECT condition_name,
       LISTAGG(
         field
         || ' ' || operation
         || ' ''' || REPLACE(value, '''', '''''') || ''''
         || ' ' || operand,
         ' '
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ordering)
         AS unique_expression
FROM   cond_rel
GROUP BY condition_name;
```

Which outputs:

> | CONDITION_NAME | UNIQUE_EXPRESSION |
> | --- | --- |
> | METHOD1 | `SHIPMENT_MODE = 'AIRWAY' AND TYP = 'BOX' OR TYP = 'ENVELOPE'` |
> | METHOD2 | `SHIPMENT_MODE = 'RAIL_ROAD' AND TYP = 'CONTAINER' AND DELIVERY_PH <> 'CALL' AND DELIVERY_TYP = 'HOUSE'` |
> | METHOD3 | `TYP = 'FRAGILE' AND DELIVERY_PH = 'TEXT' OR DELIVERY_TYP = 'OFFICE'` |
> | METHOD4 | `ACKNOWLDGE = 'YES'` |

Note:

```
TYP = 'FRAGILE' AND DELIVERY_PH = 'TEXT' OR DELIVERY_TYP = 'OFFICE'
```

means:

- either `TYP = 'FRAGILE' AND DELIVERY_PH = 'TEXT'`
- or `DELIVERY_TYP = 'OFFICE'`

and does not mean:

- `TYP = 'FRAGILE'`
- and either `DELIVERY_PH = 'TEXT'` or `DELIVERY_TYP = 'OFFICE'`

For that second option, you need to use brackets around the `OR` conditions (as per my first query).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=94ec9a14e902e3eb8813f3b4e985d6a2)*

Comment: If the OPERAND value is dynamic in nature, how do I tweak the SQL ?

Comment: @Cool_Oracle What do you mean by "dynamic in nature"?

Comment: The OPERAND value can change from AND to OR; OR to AND.

Comment: @Cool_Oracle The queries above both support both of `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: Also, may I know what is the field "comparison" in 
WITH conditions ( condition_name, comparison, operand, ordering ) AS (

Comment: @Cool_Oracle `comparison` is generated by the query in the sub-query factoring clause; it is the result of the second expression in the `SELECT` clause inside the corresponding sub-query.

Comment: I altered the tables to get ordering and it worked absolutely fine. Also, how to proceed if the operands like AND OR are to be dynamically generated ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select condition_name,
       listagg( fild || ' ' || opertion || ' ''' || value || ''' ' || opernd, ' ' )
          within group( order by 1 ) unique_expresion
  from cond_rel
 group by condition_name
```

will return an aggregated string (note that I'm using the column names you specified despite the spelling issues-- maybe you're intentionally removing random characters).  That aggregate may or may not match the value in `concat_rel` because I'm sorting by an arbitrary constant.  You may get syntactically invalid strings, you may get syntactically valid strings that are logically different than the values in `concat_rel`, you may get stings that match the values in `concat_rel`.  And that may change from execution to execution-- something that works today might not work the way you want tomorrow.  You'd need to have an additional column that you can use to sort the `cond_rel` data if you want the results to be correct.

If `value` can have apostrophes, you'd need to escape them in order to generate the correct string (`replace( value, '''', '''''' )`)